# SImple layout has unwanted large gaps

Tags: swiftui

This...

```
struct Settings: View {
    
    @AppStorage("Units") var units: String = "Miles"
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                SwiftUI.Section {
                    HStack {
                        Picker("Units", selection: $units) {
                            Text("Miles")
                            Text("Kilometres")
                        }
                        .pickerStyle(MenuPickerStyle())
                        Spacer()
                        Text(units)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Settings")
    }
}
```

=

[image]

There are two large gaps...

[image]

One below the title and one below the navigation bar.

How do I remove these gaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you already have `NavigationView` in parent of `Settings`, so just remove redundant one

```
struct Settings: View {
    
    @AppStorage("Units") var units: String = "Miles"
    
    var body: some View {
        
//        NavigationView {    // << this one should be removed !!
            Form {
```